# Swift: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct _9table: View {
    let digits: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(self.digits, id: \.self) { first in
                ForEach(self.digits, id: \.self) { second in
                    if second > first {
                        Text("\(first)+\(second)=\(first+second)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `let digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` Swift will infer the type no need to write it or short `let digits = (1...9)`

Comment: Sh_Khan thanks you answer

Answer (score 1):

According to error , you need to help compiler figure out return type so do `second -> Text? in` instead of `second  in` Try

```
struct _9table: View {
    let digits = (1...9)
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(self.digits, id: \.self) { first in
                ForEach(self.digits, id: \.self) { second -> Text? in
                    if second > first {
                        return Text("\(first)+\(second)=\(first+second)")
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it. In second foreach it must have some return. thanks your answer!

Answer (score 0):

after look other answer. Add Group was good

```
struct _9table: View {
let digits = (1...9)
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        ForEach(self.digits, id: \.self) { first in
            ForEach(self.digits, id: \.self) { second in
                Group{
                    if second > first {
                        return Text("\(first)+\(second)=\(first+second)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```